# Collection on model not updating to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a collection on a model:

```
[Table("Templates")]
public class Template
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TemplateSection> Sections { get; set; }
}

[Table("TemplateSections")]
public class TemplateSection
{
    internal TemplateSection() { Fields = new List<TemplateField>(); }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TemplateID { get; set; }

    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}
```

This appears to create the correct relationships in the database.

When I update my database any sections I have added are not saved to the database. Here's how I'm updating the dabatase:

```
Template existingtemplate = db.Templates.Find(sltemplate.ID);
db.Entry(existingtemplate).CurrentValues.SetValues(template);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If I update inspect the `existingtemplate` before `db.SaveChanges();` the Sections collection is null. Any other changes will have been updated onto `existingtemplate`.

If I add:

```
existingtemplate.Sections = template.Sections;
```

before `db.SaveChanges();` then the sections will be saved to the database but aren't reloaded if I load the template again.

Obviously I have missed something in declaring the one-to-many relationship but having read dozens of articles I can't see what it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `CurrentValues.SetValues` only sets scalar properties, in other words, the non-navigation properties.

I'm a bit surprised that `existingtemplate.Sections = template.Sections;` apparently saves the `TemplateSection` objects, but doesn't establish the associations. I would have expected it to do neither *or* both.

One way to make sure that everything is saved correctly is to first load `existingtemplate.Sections` and `Add()` each `TemplateSection` object to it. This requires a database roundtrip though.

It's more efficient to attach the `TemplateSection` objects to the context and set their `TemplateID` property.